# How to install a custom, local Python Package with Anaconda?

Tags: python, eclipse, local, pydev, anaconda

I have Anaconda2 running smoothly on Eclipse's PyDev environment.

I have received a custom package from a colleague in the form of a folder with a "library" sub-directory that contains many ".pyc" files (which I presume are the function files) and a "**init**.py" file. But no matter what I do, I cannot seem to install the folder as a package.

I have tried everything posted here in the Anaconda Prompt (which I'm assuming was the correct way of implementing the instructions)
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-non-conda-packages
but nothing worked.

I am very new to really working with Anaconda, Python, Eclipse, and PyDev (I have only written simple scripts with the default IDLE IDE in the past).

All I really want to be able to do is to use the package of functions given to me - even if they are not properly "installed", although that would be ideal. If anyone out there can help me with this I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Pyc are precompiled files, you dont need them.
You should simply import package folder with

```
import folder-name
```

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate...? I'm getting nothing but syntax errors.